# First go at my own form validation, and suggestions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well I just finished my first go at my own form validation (I always used validate plugin) for simple front end.  It's definitely small potatoes as it's only meant for a form with 4 fields; 3 required text and one required e-mail.

I'm new to Jquery so I am doing little exercises like these to help me learn and I was hoping someone could take a look and see if what I did was ok.  Did I make any newbie mistakes? Can I improve this? Perhaps I should use js objects (new to those too) to organize code? I know there is no one answer, in fact I'm sure there are countless ways to validate a form...But I was just hoping some JS expert could offer a little insight on better coding practices.

**EDIT - forgot to mention...I'm aware that I should probably use regex for better email validation, however, just threw the indexOf() method for the time being **

```
$(function() {

        var err = "<span class='error'>Required field.</span>";
        var errEmail = "<span class='error'>Please enter valid email.</span>";
        var errors = false;

        $('.submit').click(function() {
            $('.error').remove();

            $('.req').each(function() {
                if($(this).val() == '') {
                    $(this).after(err);
                    errors = true;
                } 
            });

            if ($('.reqe').val().indexOf('@') === -1) {
                $('.reqe').after(errEmail);
                errors = true;
            }

            if (errors == true) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                var errors = false;
                alert("Submitted");
                return true;
            }

        });
});
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of small changes:

1. near the end:

   ```
   if (errors == true) {
       return false;
   }
   else {
       var errors = false;
       alert("Submitted");
       return true;
   }
   ```

   Could be:

   ```
   if(!errors)
   {
       alert("Submitted");
   }
   return !errors;
   ```
2. the `.req`

   ```
   if($(this).val() == ''){
   ```

   could be:

   ```
   if(!$(this).val()){
   ```

   This would actually be a problem because

   ```
    " " != ""
   ```

   so a space would validate *(if that's what you intended then ignore this one ;) )*
3. `var errors= false;` needs to be inside the click event:

   ```
    $('.submit').click(function() {
        var errors = false;
   ```

   otherwise when you click the submit a second time after an invalid attempt it won't reset the value.

**Alternatively:-**

http://jsfiddle.net/ssTPm/

```
var validationConfig = [
{
    "selector": ".req",
    "hasErrors": function() {
        return !$(this).val()
    },
    "errorMessage": "<span class='error'>Required field.</span>"},
{
    "selector": '.reqe',
    "hasErrors": function() {
        return $('.reqe').val().indexOf('@') === -1
    },
    "errorMessage": "<span class='error'>Please enter valid email.</span>"
}];
```

then a nice loop like:

```
for (var i = 0, validation = null; validation = validationConfig[i]; i++) {
    $(validation.selector).each(validateEach);
}
```

and validateEach would look like:

```
 function validateEach () {
    var hasErrors = validation.hasErrors.call(this);
    errors |= hasErrors;
    if (hasErrors) {
        $(this).after(validation.errorMessage);
    }
};
```

This would mean you could have the validation function in you js files and then when you initialise the page from the server you just output the validationConfig:

```
validationConfig = validationConfig || [];
validationConfig.concat([
    {
        "selector": ... 
    }
];
```

as many times as you like. Although from the looks of things it might be over-engineering things a bit.

**Explanations:-**

so the `||` is a coalesce or OR operator.

```
myVariable = myVariable || [];
```

means if `myVariable` results in a true value *(not `false`, `undefined`, `null` etc etc)* then it does nothing otherwise it assigns it a defualt value.

so if I had the following:

```
myList = myList|| [];
myList.push(1);
myList = myList|| [];
myList.push(2);
myList = myList|| [];
myList.push(3);
```

it would result in `[1,2,3]`. The first time it sets the value as `[]` the next times they just assign itself to itself. This way it doesn't need to know if it has been initialised or not.

the `|=` is a bitwise `|` *(BITWISE OR)* and an `=` so

```
value |= otherValue;
```

is the equivalent to

```
value = value | otherValue;
```

In this example

```
errors |= hasErrors;
```

is the exact same as

```
errors = errors || hasErrors;
```

Errors is assigned `true` as long as either it was already `true` or `hasErrors` is `true`;